# What is the difference between using the '@patch.object' and 'with patch.object' in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

In writing unit tests for my application, I have always been using the `@mock.patch` and `@patch.object` decorators. But now, for some unit tests when I use the decorator, I receive an error '**TypeError: staticmethod object is not an iterator**'.

But with the same code, if I use `mock.patch.object` or `mock.patch.object`, everything works just fine.

For example, in my test class I have this method:

```
@staticmethod
def my_mock():
   ...do something
```

When I try the following unit test

```
@mock.patch('mypackage.mymodule.my_method', side_effect=my_mock)
def test_something(self, my_method_mocked):
    ...test something
```

I receive the error message stated before '**TypeError: staticmethod object is not an iterator**'.

But when I try this way

```
def test_something(self):
    with patch.object(mymodule, "my_method") as mocked_method:
        mocked_method.side_effect = self.my_mock
        ...test something
```

then everything works perfectly.

I've read the Python documentation about mock and unit tests, but I couldn't find any explanation for this behavior.

What is the difference between using the **decorator pattern** and the **with** pattern? Where I can find more about this?

Just to be more clear, this my code structure:

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def my_mock():
    ...mock
        return service

    # doesn't work
    @mock.patch('mypackage.mymodule.my_method', side_effect=my_mock)
    def test_something(self, my_method_mocked):
        ...test something

    # work 
    def test_something(self):
    with patch.object(mymodule, "my_method") as mocked_method:
        mocked_method.side_effect = self.my_mock
        ...test something
```

That's why I can't do `TestClass.my_mock`. If I do, I get a reference error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of Python's descriptor protocol. The difference is not in how you are calling `patch`, but in the value you are assigning to the `side_effect` attribute in each case.

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def my_mock():
        pass

    print type(my_mock)    # As in your decorator case

# As in your context manager case
print type(A.my_mock)
print type(A().my_mock)
```

If you run this code, you'll see that the `print` statement inside the class declaration outputs `<type 'staticmethod'>`, because you have a reference to the method itself.

The other two `print` statements output `<type 'function'>` because you *don't* have a reference to the method; you have a reference to the return value of the method's `__get__` method. The two calls are equivalent to

```
print type(A.__dict__['my_mock'].__get__(A))
print type(A.__dict__['my_mock'].__get__(A()))
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html for a fuller discussion of how descriptors are used to implement the three types of methods (static, class, and instance).

---

The actual error comes about because `patch` expects a callable as the value of the `side_effect` argument, and failing that, it needs an iterable of return values. A `staticmethod` object is neither callable nor iterable.
(Try it: `A.__dict__['my_mock']()`.)

To ensure you get the function, you need to access the method through the class.

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def my_mock():
        "whatever it does"

@mock.patch('mypackage.mymodule.my_method', side_effect=Foo.my_mock)
def test_something(self, my_method_mocked):
    ...test something
```

Comment: But I can only reference method like this Foo.my_mock when they are `@classmethod`. With `@staticmethod` doesn't work.

Comment: `Foo.my_mock` is *exactly* how you need to access a static method. The only difference between a static method and a class method is that the static method doesn't get a reference to the class as an argument.

Comment: If I try use like you said `Foo.my_mock` with `my_mock` as a static method, I got an error saying that I can't do that. But with I declare `my_mock` as a class method, than I can use it.

Comment: There is no such message that says "[you] can't do that". Be precise.

Comment: My mock method 'my_mock' is inside of my test class. So if I try to use `side_effect=TestClass.my_mock` in a test method that is inside the same class of my_mock I get a reference error.

Comment: If the patch occurs *during* class creation, then you can refer to it as `my_mock`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the class name

```
class mymodule:
    @staticmethod
    def my_mock():
        ...do something
...

@mock.patch('mypackage.mymodule.my_method', side_effect=mymodule.my_mock)
def test_something(self, my_method_mocked):
    ...test something
```